# get all parent table data but only data of child which meet condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi I have 2 tables like this :

**parent is like this**

```
class Policy(Base):
    """table containing details for Policies"""

    __tablename__ = "UmbrellaPolicy"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    policy_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    user_defined_name = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
```

**and child is like this**

```
class Site(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Site"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    policy_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Policy.id"))
    site_id = Column(String(32), nullable=False, index=True)
    policy = relationship("Policy", backref="sites")
```

now I want to get all data of Policy table but data of site table only where site_id = 100 . how I will do this in orm ? I mean sql alchemy ? kindly guide

**Currently doing this but it will bring all policies:** who I can restrict to just get just sites which have site_id = 100

```
policies = (
            session.query(Policy)
            .join(Site)
            .filter(
                Policy.user_defined_name == 'yes',
            )
            .all()
        )
```

**will this be done using leftjoins ? but how I can use that in flask?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it's more like a pseudocode), should return id's of needed policies:

```
def get_policies() -> list:
      return [s.policy_id for s in site.all().filter(site_id=100)]
```

That will return a list of policies objects

Comment: there is no any query solution for it ? this seems so expensive